# Issue achieving port forwarding on Azure VM Windows Server 2012

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, azure

I have an Azure VM with Windows Server 2012. It is running a Java application that binds and listens on a specific IP/port.

The server has an external IP, and is reachable on it (I RDP to it without issue).

The application requires an IP to bind to. I have tried:

- External IP: java.net.BindException (which is understandable, as the machine does not know it has an external IP - ipconfig only reveals internal IP: 10.0.0.4)
- 0.0.0.0 - can't reach from the Internet
- 10.0.0.4 (internal IP) - can't reach from the Internet

I have accessed the Network Security Group, which is associated with both the Network Interface as well as the Subnet. I have created Inbound and Outbound rules, allowing 'Any' protocol, 'Any' source, 'Any' destination, and the port used by the java application. All online sources tell me that this should suffice.

I have restarted the VM, but that did not help.

What can I check? What did I miss?

Comment: Can you access this java application on Azure VM? Does this application running? please run this command to check it `netstat -ant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, we should binding your application to `0.0.0.0` or `10.0.0.4`.

For your scenarrio, we should check the application **running** or not, we can use this command to check it:

```
netstat -ant
```

By the way, we can use `telnet` to test the public IP address with this port. Also we should check our **local network settings**, are there something block it.

Also, we should check **windows firewall**, we should add port to inbound rules.

Comment: I indeed forgot about windows firewall. I will check it tonight and respond back. Thank's for the tip!

Comment: @Gerino Just want to confirm the current situations.

Please feel free to let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: I added Incoming rule into the Windows Firewall. Such an obvious omission on my part. Thank you so much! <3